# How to shim jQueryUI with RequireJS?

Tags: jquery-ui, requirejs

I prefer to use the require, jQuery and jQueryUI as seperate scripts without modifying them.

I get the error: (inside jquery-ui.min.js:6)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

jQuery itself works and can be used, however jQuery-UI doesnt work.

How can I solve it without using require-jquery by just modying main.js

Here my current main.js

```
requirejs.config({

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery/jquery',
        'jqueryui': 'lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },
        'jqueryui': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

require([
    "jquery",
    "jqueryui"], function(jQuery) {    
});
```

I experimented with various things like the shim init function, which however is not even called before the exception happens.

Any ideas, or impossible?

Update: fixed the code above. Its working now!

Comment: there is extra : in your shim configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in your code, you wrote this

```
'jqueryui:': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        }
```

do you notice the extra `:` . Remove it and then your code is working

Comment: thanks, yes that works now ;) I already was doubting it is possible so I didn't expect to have an simple error like that.